# When does knockout binding require second parameter?

Tags: knockout.js

An upgrade to knockout 3.5 gave this error.

> Uncaught Error: ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node
>       at a.uc (knockout-3.5.0.js:84)
>       at Object.ko.applyBindings (knockout.validation.js:1472)
>       at 0abf30a2-e1f1-41cf-8ecb-f87ca5776794:946

I tested on a test plunkr and confirmed the second parameter is still optional in the new version.

In what circumstances does the second parameter become required?

Comment: You've posted an error without the code that generated it. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From official [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of
>   the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example,
>   ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,
>   document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the
>   activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants,
>   which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate
>   each with a different region of the page.